# how do I ask a community-wiki question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have a question that I know should be community wiki.  I don't see that option, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask it, then mark it for moderator attention.  Only moderators can mark things community wiki, iirc.

Edit: See Robert's answer [here](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/whats-the-criteria-for-accepting-an-answer/63#63)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find before asking the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.